# How do I use javascript in atreal.richfile.preview code in Plone?

Tags: python, plone

I wish to add javascript in atreal.richfile.preview egg. How do I do that? Actually I wish to disable copy/paste in the preview viewlet while previewing doc/xls/pdf file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ZMI, at /MySite/portal_view_customizations/atreal.richfile.preview.interfaces.ipreview-rfpreview

use custom code with the javascript as:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title tal:content="here/Title"></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 65) {
          return false;
      }
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 67) {
         return false;
      }
      if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 86) {
         return false;
      }

    return true;
}
   document.oncontextmenu = function(){
        return false;
    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body tal:content="structure view/getPreview" >

</body>
</html>
```